# Problem formatting list view with Json

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, json-formatting

I am trying to format a list with Json. I want elements in the list to turn red if the value in one column is "No". 
I found an example on the internet, added my own values and deleted som conditions that I did not need. But it wont work. What am I missing?

```
{
"schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
"additionalRowClass": "=if([$In_x0020_Workday] == 'No', 'sp-field-severity--blocked', '')"
}
```

Regards
Maria

Answer (score 0):

Use true/false as condition:

```
{
  "schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": "=if([$In_x0020_Workday] == false, 'sp-field-severity--blocked', '')"
}
```